# Ruby: creating a matrix with diagonal band of 1,2,1

Tags: ruby, arrays, matrix

Before we start, plz understand that I am a total beginner at ruby and computer programming, i possess no prior knowledge and need the programming to be the most basic of the basic or else i cannot understand. I am currently doing a project for school and am stuck.

I have to create a code in ruby for a matrix A with n rows and n columns that is banded with values [2,1]

```
[2,1,0,0,0]
[1,2,1,0,0]
[0,1,2,1,0]
[0,0,1,2,1]
```

I made a code but dont know why it is wrong and where.. plz help!!

```
def make1d(n)
  a = Array.new(n)
   for i in 0..(n-1)
    a[i] = 0
  end
  a
end
def make2d(height,width)
  a = Array.new(height)
  for i in 0..(height-1)
    a[i] = make1d(width)
  end
  a
end
def matrixa(n)
 a=make2d(n,n)
  for k in 0..n-2
  a[k][k]=2
  a[k+1][k]=1
  a[k][k+1]=1
  a[n-1][n-1]=2
  end
 a
end
```

Comment: Can you saw what is not working? I tried `matrixa(5)` and it returned `[[2, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 2]]`. Looks exactly like what you wanted.

Comment: This code returns the wrong result `[[0]]` for `n = 1`, it should be `[[2]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has some great features you can take advantage of. For example, `Array.new` takes a block (`do ... end`) to specify a default value. This block gets the current index as parameter (`do |index| ... end`). Perfect for this scenario!

Your logic seems quite complex for just setting values on the diagonal. If you take a step back, what makes a diagonal special if you only look at the row and column indices? Right, they are equal. If you go one diagonal to the right/left, all the row and col indices are off by one, and so on.

So here’s how I would write the code:

```
Array.new(n) do |row|
  Array.new(n) do |col|
    case row - col
    when -1 then 1
    when 0 then 2
    when 1 then 1
    else 0
    end
  end
end
```

Or you can make it even shorter, and also handle the general case. Just substitute `2` with the value you want, or make it a function parameter

```
Array.new(n) do |row|
  Array.new(n) do |col|
    [2 - (row - col).abs, 0].max
  end
end
```